# Using mysqli_num_rows with while loop and onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, mysql-num-rows

I want to echo number of rows(suppose numer of rows= 3).if the user clicks on the number(I am passing 1  parrameter from while loop),then data is alerted
But the problem is that

1. if I echo numrows inside while loop then all rows(related 3 rows data ) are alerted on onclick event,but numrows are shown 3 times like 333.
2. If I echo outside of while loop,then num rows are show one time but Only one result is passed to the function.

I also used count(col),but this way only one result is retrieved.

Any solution to show the number of  rows one time but passing all the results of $uid(which is in while loop) to onclick function?.Plz help.

```
  $sql=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * from user_data where  scid='$scid'");
            $num=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                $uid=$row['uid'];



                ?>


            <span onclick=o4_sameby_scid(<?php echo $uid;  ?>)><?php echo  $num  ?></span>



            <script type="text/javascript">

                function o4_sameby_scid(o4_id) {
                    alert(o4_id);
                }


            </script>



            <?php
            }
```

Comment: @itachi results of $uid in while loop

Comment: The question is vague. Explain `Any solution to show the num rows one time but passing all the results to onclick function?` this part. May be with an example.

Comment: @itachi.plz review the question.I have updated the above line

Comment: in what format? As in `1,2,3,....` or different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are nesting the wrong parts of your code inside of your `while` loop. What about this approach?:

```
<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * from user_data where  scid='$scid'");
$num=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

$allvalues = array();

//  Do all looping before any echoing
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    // add this row's value to an array of all values
    $allvalues[] = $uid=$row['uid'];
}

// implode this array
$valuesascsv = implode(', ', $allvalues);


//  This is echo'd outside of the loop, because we only need to see it one time
echo '<span onclick=o4_sameby_scid("'. $valuesascsv .'")>'. $num .' results found! </span>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function o4_sameby_scid(o4_id) {
        alert(o4_id);
    }
</script>
```

This should output:

```
<span onclick=o4_sameby_scid("uid#1, uid#2, uid#3")>3 results found!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function o4_sameby_scid(o4_id) {
        alert(o4_id);
    }
</script>
```

Clicking on any of the row count should alert all of the UIDs.

Is this the behavior you were looking for?

Comment: ,Thank u.Exactly,i want the same results,but could u plz take the while loop out, from the alert(before javascript tags) to make it more  simple?